# Serialize an Object Array to sent over Sockets

Tags: java, arrays, sockets, serialization, object

I have an array that I have created from a database ResultSet. I am trying to Serialize it so that I can send it over a socket stream. At the moment I am getting an error telling me that the array is not Serializable. The code I have is down below, the first part is the class to create an object for the array:

```
class ProteinData
{
    private int ProteinKey;

    public ProteinData(Integer ProteinKey)
    {
        this.ProteinKey = ProteinKey;
    }

    public Integer getProteinKey() {
        return this.ProteinKey;
    }

    public void setProteinKey(Integer ProteinKey) {
         this.ProteinKey = ProteinKey;
    }
}
```

The code to populate the array:

```
public List<ProteinData> readJavaObject(String query, Connection con) throws Exception
    {        
        PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
        query_results = stmt.executeQuery();
        while (query_results.next())
        {
            ProteinData pro = new ProteinData();
            pro.setProteinKey(query_results.getInt("ProteinKey"));
            tableData.add(pro);
        }
        query_results.close();
        stmt.close();
        return tableData;
    }
```

And the code to call this is:

```
List dataList = (List) this.readJavaObject(query, con);
ObjectOutputStream output_stream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
output_stream.writeObject(dataList);
```

And the code recieving this is:

```
List dataList = (List) input_stream.readObject();
```

Can someone help me serailize this array. All I can find in forums is simple arrays(EG. int[]).

I tried to add the serializable to the class and the UID number but got `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: socketserver.ProteinData` error message. Does anyone now why?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I can't see any Array within your code... only List<T>

Comment: if the `readJavaObject()` method post here is the full method, you are going to have other problems down the line as it seems like you are using a class-level List to return results for each method call.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically you need that the classes you want to serialize are implementing `Serializable`. And if you want to avoid the warning related to the serial you should have also a `long serialVersionUID`for each one, that is a code used to distinguish your specific version of the class. Read a tutorial like [this one](http://forums.techarena.in/guides-tutorials/1332706.htm) to get additional info, serialization is not so hard to handle..

However remember that serialization is faulty when used between two different versions of the JVM (and it has some flaws in general).

Just a side note: the interface `Serializable`doesn't actually give any required feature to the class itself (it's not a typical interface) and it is used just to distinguish between classes that are supposed to be sent over streams and all the others. Of course, if a class is `Serializable`, all the component it uses (instance variables) must be serializable too to be able to send the whole object.

Answer (score 4):

Change your class declaration to:

class ProteinData **implements Serializable** {
...
}

Answer (score 1):

I would have thought as a minimum that you would need

class ProteinData **implements Serializable**
and a

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1234556L;
(Eclipse will generate the magic number for you).
in the class.